# What is the fundamental meaning of due?

Tags: word-meaning

I have searched due on dictionaries.
But I can't know what is the fundamental meaning of due.
In my opinion, due means something is expected. 
But I am not sure whether it is really correct or not.
Please, teach me this word.

Answer (score 1):

The roots of this word can be traced all the way back to its Latin progenitor the verb [*debere*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/debeo#Latin) which means *to owe*. So, if something is due, it means that it must be done because you're under obligation to do it.

Comment: So due has exactly same meaning of owe?

Comment: Yes, something like that.

Comment: Would you think it is right that English learners should study English words by looking on roots of words?

Comment: I can't be bothered to search right word meaning taking much time. what should I do about this problem?..

Comment: If it feels like it's going to help you, you could definitely learn the origins of words you're studying.

Comment: The easy way to look up the origin of a word is to type the following in the Google search box: "[your word] definition". Then, expand the list of meanings and at the very bottom of it you'll see some information pertaining to the origin of the word.

Comment: Thank you a lot. that will help me to study English words.